# How to set "nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true" in MiNifi config.yml

Tags: apache-nifi

I can't get Site to Site working on MiNiFi (JAVA). I have enabled all security properties in the config.yml file still the generated nifi.properties does not include **nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true** 
any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

As of version 0.5.0, Apache NiFi MiNiFi does not support acting as a Site to Site server. This is different than NiFi because S2S requires leveraging NiFi's UI. Since MiNiFi doesn't have a UI, it is non-trivial to add (here's a ticket describing it [1]).

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINIFI-133

Comment: Thank you @JDP... How then do I get MiNiFi to ship files to a Remote secured NiFi instance ?